# Iterate over tuple elements with std::apply

Tags: c++, lambda, tuples, c++17

I wanted to archieve a way of applying a function to each element of a given tuple and I came up with a solution that is demonstrated in the following example.

```
int main()
{
    std::apply([](auto&&... xs)
               { 
                   [](...){}(([](auto&& x){ std::cout << x << "\n"; }(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)), false)...); 
               }, std::make_tuple(1, 2.f, 3.0));
}
```

This seems to work fine except that the tuple elements seem to be processed in an inverted order, leading to the following output:

**3**
**2**
**1**

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order in which the arguments to your inner, empty lambda `[](...){}` are evaluated is unspecified (even after the [paper on evaluation order](http://wg21.link/p0145)).

Just use a fold on the comma operator:

```
std::apply([](auto&&... xs) {
               ((std::cout << std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs) << '\n'), ...); },
           std::make_tuple(1, 2.f, 3.0));
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t6CLUC07RFilsN8t). Or binary-fold over `cout` directly. Once we introduce an "packize" operator, for which there's a proposal out already (using `[:]`), you could also write `(std::cout << [:]tup << '\n'), ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I decided to use something like this: `template<typename Function, typename Tuple>
void for_each(Function&& function, Tuple&& tuple)
{
    std::apply([&function](auto&&... xs){ (function(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)), ...); }, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple));   
}

int main()
{
    for_each([](auto&& x){ std::cout << x << "\n"; }, std::make_tuple(1, 2.f, 3.0));
}`